# JQuery Increment Select Id

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

I am cloning a select option input so the user can add more services.  I have got the cloning part working fine but when I submit the form I am only getting the first original select appearing.

I think I need to increment the select id e.g. id="serviceId_2"

I have searched and searched but I cant find how to increment the ID.

JQuery

```
$('#clone').click(function() {
    var original = $('#serviceId:eq(0)');
    var allSelects = $('#serviceId');
    var clone = original.clone();

    $('select', clone).filter(function(i) {             

        allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
        allSelects.attr('id','asda');

    }).remove();



    $('#target').append(clone).append('<br />');
});
```

Anyone had a similar problem?

Cheers

J

Answer (score 0):

```
var original = $('#serviceId:eq(0)');
var allSelects = $('#serviceId');
var clone = original
                  .clone()
                  .attr('id', 'serviceId_' + $('select[id^=serviceId]').length + 1);
```

Count length of existing `select` with `id` started with `serviceId` and then increase `1` to make unique.

or If you want just clone one time the its simple

```
var clone = original.clone().attr('id', 'serviceId_2');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `original.clone().attr()`, not `original.attr().clone()`? Also, note this will not work properly if `select` elements are removed.

Comment: I have added the code but still no joy.  Any thoughts? Cheers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KyW28/6/ create the basic and used alert command to see the params and serviceId is repeated not incremented?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
var clone = original.clone().attr('id', 'serviceId_2');
```

Your function it not very clear and so I am not going to put out the full code here.. The idea is to use `.attr` after clone to change the `ID` of the cloned element.